# NSDate and PHP echo out

Tags: php, cocoa

i use the Predicate Editor to make Filter and save results to mysql. 
Dates will be saved (Today) as: 316077618.500794

My Question:
How can i calculate this in a PHP Time? I want to echo out this date as a Realdate but i find no way how to calc this for php.

I cant modify in cocoa code, it must be format out in PHP.

I need help :)

Thank you very much.

Comment: What logic is used to get that date representation?

Comment: I think 316077618.500794 is the number of seconds elapsed from Unix epoch start 1970/01/01 00:00:00 +0000 right? In Cocoa: [today timeIntervalSince1970];

Comment: Are you sure that 316077618 is actually "Jan 17 2011" and not "Jan 07 2011" ?

Answer (score 2):

[NSDate Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Tells me :

> The sole primitive method of NSDate, timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate, provides the basis for all the other methods in the NSDate interface. This method returns a time value relative to an absolute reference date—the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT.

You have 2 options:

1. Modify your cocoa code to export the date in a familiar format. (Yes, this may not be an option, but it will honestly be the easiest)
2. Do the calculation yourself. There is danger in this, in that you've got to be sure that you don't mess up the timezone. In it's simplest, it's 978307200 + NSDate.

Comment: I think don't think that (2) is so dangerous. The PHP function `time()` returns seconds since 1970 GMT, so the difference is merely a number. Also, your number is wrong: it's 978307200 (see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSTimeIntervalSince1970 )

Comment: Yes, sorry I calculated from 1991 instead of 2001.. It's a monday morning.

Answer (score 0):

oh thank you :)
The Soulution is:

```
$NSDATE='-61737774.586439';
$d=mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2001)+ ($NSDATE) ;
echo date("d.m.Y",$d);
```

:D

Hope helps :)

Comment: Remember to first set the timezone like this: `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Vienna')`.